# angular ui popover on options list

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, popover

I have a list of options that are occasionally longer than the width of the container; and am trying to implement a popover to show the user the whole width of the text. When I inspect the elements on my page, the popover properties and classes are applied, but I do not see any popovers. I am using [angular ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.3.2/#/popover).

**html**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <label>Available Routines</label>
      <select size="8" style="width: 99%;">
         <option ng-repeat="item in itemList"
            uib-popover="item" popover-trigger="mouseenter">
                {{item}}
        </option>
     </select>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.itemList = [
    "item1","item2","item3","item4","item5",
    "item6","item7","item8","item9","item10",
    "item11","item12","item13","item14","item15",
]
```

is there a limitation to popovers in a list select?